# Can't run Minecraft on windowed mode

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I can run minecraft properly, but only on fullscreen. I cant switch to windowed mode, when i do, Minecraft is completely blank, black or even transparent. I don't know what to do, So could anyone please help me :(

Comment: By the way, it's also happening to Friday night funkin', I won't update my video graphic card driver, Because it's the only one that supports the resolution of my screen.

Comment: @EusekeraSV You will have to update driver unfortunately, if you could give specs of your pc and graphic driver's current version then I might be able to help.

Answer (score -1):

if you playing on windows 10 you may have to go into the Minecraft Launcher settings and fix this issue or just re-download the version.
If you are playing on Mac devices and it goes transparent there is normally a system update that could cause the issue, backup your worlds then get the system update.

Edit: also may be your Graphics card and what version you are playing on.